Anyone who worked with flutter app and Epson thermal printer - I have a question
I want to print POS receipt while using flutter app.
I want to do print using flutter app while connecting to an Epson thermal printer, I try different packages but I have issues.
epson_epos 0.0.2 

I want to enter ip address of the Epson thermal printer, and flutter app should connect to the printer and on function call it give me a receipt.

How will you manage if the device is connected to a different network (e.g. poor wifi signal so it switches over to 4G/LTE?)
